# I need to optimize a large data table in a mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in a mysql DB with about 6 mil rows of data. Structure below. Most of my queries are searching for specific "customer" fields and display a value for each customer according to the value in column "value". The query searches the whole Table to match those customers specified in the query.  This table started rather small but now it's gotten too big and my queries are taking quite some time to retrieve results. My questions is the following: If i create a separate table with just the customer field, along with an index, will that make my customer queries faster?

```
TABLE `data` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `entry_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_type` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `rate` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NUCREATELL,
  `value` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `page` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sector` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `product` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `supplier` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `promoted_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `hasimage` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Add an index on whatever column you are consistently using in your `WHERE` clause. Like `WHERE value = 'something'`... add an index on `value`. If you share a typical query or two that you would submit on this table we may be able to help more.

Comment: Please include an explain plan in your question so we can see where the bottlenecks might be in your query.

Comment: `data` is a table name that raises eyebrows. A database table usally contains an entity, say a customer, a product, a supplier, a city, whatever. Or a relation such as product_in_store, or supplier_has_product. But `data`? What is this supposed to be? It seems to me you haven't even really started building a database. Think about which entities you are dealing with. And build separate tables for these. A relational database can be very fast, but only if you use it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You want an index.

If you are searching for customers using `in` or `=` (the most common methods), then you can use a standard index on `customer`.

If you have more complex searches -- say using `like` with a leading wildcard -- then this does not work.  A full text index might help.  Or it might not, depending on the nature of the query and the data.

Answer (score 0):

The "separate table" you're thinking about should be an index on your main table.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name 
ON data(customer,value);
```

This will speed up the queries, and even prevent access to the table itself, at the cost of slightly slower INSERT and UPDATE operations.